# How can i create a file for JSONmodel programmatically and automatically create its Codable struct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, codable

How can i build a function that takes string as a parameter, that string will be my JSONObject and then this function will create a file in project that contains a struct which have keys of my model like this page does https://app.quicktype.io

I will pass this kind of string to function:

```
  [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }]
```

It will create a file in project like:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - UserInfoModelElement
struct UserInfoModelElement: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, username, email: String
    let address: Address
    let phone, website: String
    let company: Company
}

// MARK: - Address
struct Address: Codable {
    let street, suite, city, zipcode: String
    let geo: Geo
}

// MARK: - Geo
struct Geo: Codable {
    let lat, lng: String
}

// MARK: - Company
struct Company: Codable {
    let name, catchPhrase, bs: String
}

typealias UserInfoModel = [UserInfoModelElement]
```

Comment: If this pages are doing this, it is obvious it is possible

Comment: Yes you are right I should change my question as "How can i build?" :)

Comment: Try this extension https://apps.apple.com/us/app/paste-json-as-code-quicktype/id1330801220?mt=12 or something like sourcery

Comment: Thank you but their browser doing also same think i wonder how can i do it with only xcode and swift also without using library

Comment: if you want it the hard way, did you try anything? first parse son find all objects etc?

Comment: Yes i am parsing with regular way, actually i am building an SDK for myself to use it every project and i have tried to create automatically build model but failed need to find out how to do it, for now easiest way is https://app.quicktype.io

Answer (score 0):

I'm building exactly this as an open source project on GitHub juliofruta/CodableCode. Feel free to submit a Pull request since this does not support all cases as specified in the comments. I'm copy and pasting my current solution here:

```
import Foundation

enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case invalidData
}

let identation = "    "

extension String {
    
    var asType: String {
        var string = self
        let firstChar = string.removeFirst()
        return firstChar.uppercased() + string
    }
    
    var asSymbol: String {
        var string = self
        let firstChar = string.removeFirst()
        return firstChar.lowercased() + string
    }
    
    mutating func lineBreak() {
        self = self + "\n"
    }
    
    func makeCodableTypeArray(anyArray: [Any], key: String, margin: String) throws -> String {
        var types = Set<String>()
        var existingTypes = Set<String>()
        var structCodeSet = Set<String>()
        
        try anyArray.forEach { jsonObject in
            
            var type: String?
            
            // check what type is each element of the array
            switch jsonObject {
            case _ as String:
                type = "String"
            case _ as Bool:
                type = "Bool"
            case _ as Decimal:
                type = "Decimal"
            case _ as Double:
                type = "Double"
            case _ as Int:
                type = "Int"
            case let dictionary as [String: Any]:
                let objectData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
                let objectString = String(data: objectData, encoding: .utf8)!
                let dummyTypeImplementation = try objectString.codableCode(name: "TYPE", margin: "")
                
                // if the existing type does not contain the dummy type implementation
                if !existingTypes.contains(dummyTypeImplementation) {
                    // insert it
                    existingTypes.insert(dummyTypeImplementation)
                    // keep a count
                    if existingTypes.count == 1 {
                        type = key.asType
                    } else {
                        type = key.asType + "\(existingTypes.count)"
                    }
                    // and get the actual implementation
                    let typeImplementation = try objectString.codableCode(name: type!, margin: margin + identation)
                    structCodeSet.insert(typeImplementation)
                }
            default:
                type = ""
                assertionFailure() // unhandled case
            }
            if let unwrappedType = type {
                types.insert(unwrappedType)
            }
        }
        
        // write type
        var swiftCode = ""
        
        if types.isEmpty {
            swiftCode += "[Any]"
        } else if types.count == 1 {
            swiftCode += "[\(types.first!)]"
        } else {
            
            swiftCode += "\(key.asType)Options"
            
            // TODO: Instead of enum refactor to use optionals where needed.
            // TODO: Build Swift Build package plugin
            // Use diffing algorithm to introduce optionals?
            // Introduce strategies:
            // create
            // 1. enum withassociated types
            // 2. optionals where needed
            // 3. optionals everywhere
            
            // add support to automatically fix when reserved keywords have reserved words for example:
            // let return: Return // this does not compile and is part of the bitso api
            // so add support for coding keys
//
//            struct Landmark: Codable {
//                var name: String
//                var foundingYear: Int
//                var location: Coordinate
//                var vantagePoints: [Coordinate]
//
//                enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//                    case name = "return"
//                    case foundingYear = "founding_date"
//
//                    case location
//                    case vantagePoints
//                }
//            }
            
            
            // create enum
            swiftCode.lineBreak()
            swiftCode.lineBreak()
            swiftCode += margin + identation + "enum \(key.asType)Options: Codable {"
            
            types.forEach { type in
                swiftCode.lineBreak()
                // enum associatedTypes
                swiftCode += margin + identation + identation + "case \(type.asSymbol)(\(type))"
            }
            
            swiftCode.lineBreak()
            swiftCode += margin + identation + "}"
        }
        
        // write implementations
        structCodeSet.forEach { implementation in
            swiftCode.lineBreak()
            swiftCode.lineBreak()
            swiftCode += implementation            
            swiftCode.lineBreak()
        }
        
        return swiftCode
    }
    
    /// Compiles a valid JSON to a Codable Swift Type as in the following Grammar spec: https://www.json.org/json-en.html
    /// - Parameter json: A valid JSON string
    /// - Throws: Not sure if it should throw right now. We can check if the JSON is valid inside
    /// - Returns: The string of the type produced by the JSON
    public func codableCode(name: String, margin: String = "") throws -> String {
        var swiftCode = ""
        swiftCode += margin + "struct \(name.asType): Codable {"
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else {
            throw Error.invalidData
        }        
        if let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            try dictionary
                .sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
                .forEach { pair in
                let (key, value) = pair
                swiftCode.lineBreak()
                swiftCode += margin + identation + "let \(key.asSymbol): "
                switch value {
                case _ as Bool:
                    swiftCode += "Bool"
                case _ as String:
                    swiftCode += "String"
                case _ as Decimal:
                    swiftCode += "Decimal"
                case _ as Double:
                    swiftCode += "Double"
                case _ as Int:
                    swiftCode += "Int"
                case let jsonObject as [String: Any]:
                    let objectData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: [])
                    let objectString = String(data: objectData, encoding: .utf8)!
                    swiftCode += "\(key.asType)"
                    swiftCode.lineBreak()
                    swiftCode.lineBreak()
                    swiftCode += try objectString.codableCode(name: key, margin: margin + identation)
                    swiftCode.lineBreak()
                case let anyArray as [Any]:
                    swiftCode += try makeCodableTypeArray(anyArray: anyArray, key: key, margin: margin)
                // TODO: Add more cases like dates
                default:
                    swiftCode += "Any"
                }
            }
        }
        swiftCode.lineBreak()
        swiftCode += margin + "}"
        return swiftCode
    }
    
    public var codableCode: String? {
        try? codableCode(name: "<#SomeType#>")
    }
}
```